# convert mutilple nodes within xml to comma seperated list in Tsql

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery, string-concatenation

I have a table with a column containing the following xml which I want to present on the gui as a comma separated list ie. 1,2,5,6,7,8

```
    <RuleSetting>
  <CurrentQueue>1559</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1560</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1561</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1564</CurrentQueue>
</RuleSetting>
```

How might I do this or where can I find information on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XQuery` for this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<RuleSetting>
  <CurrentQueue>1559</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1560</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1561</CurrentQueue>
  <CurrentQueue>1564</CurrentQueue>
</RuleSetting>';

SELECT STUFF(@xml.query(N'
                   for $nd in /RuleSetting/CurrentQueue/text()
                   return
                   <x>{concat(",",$nd)}</x>
                   ').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

If you can be sure, that your data will never include any blanks, you might use this simple approach:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@xml.query(N'data(/RuleSetting/CurrentQueue)')
                   .value(N'.',N'nvarchar(max)'),' ',',');
```

Hint: `XQuery` function `data()` will return all values separated by a blank, which you can replace on string level.

Comment: shnugo, if those id's were primary keys how would I run  a select statement on each of those id's  i.e select * from table where id=1559

Comment: @Ageis, please avoid *follow-up* questions... The principle *1-issue-1-qestion* allows to understand SO as a huge archive of solutions. *Follow-ups* would destroy this. A second point: New questions pull the highest attraction. People will rush in to help. So please place a new question (you might add a link to this one) and place a comment here to give me an alert. Thx